# Azure Functions with IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I am asking myself whether it is a good idea to have an Azure Function consuming events directly from the EventHub compatible IoT Hub endpoint.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901284/azure-functions-event-hub-trigger-bindings) Azure Functions use EventHubProcessorHost to consume the events. It also indicates that if a Function seems sluggish the scaling logic kicks in and creates more instances of a Function (e.g. per IoT Hub partition).

What is the trigger for the scaling logic? Number of unprocessed messages? Processing duration of a single message (would not be a good metric)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaling logic looks at the total number of unprocessed messages remaining in all the partitions of the EventHub.

Comment: Please note that this is only the case if using the Consumption Plan, if using the App Service Plan, you are responsible for scaling: You select the metric to scale on and you determine the threshold that triggers scaling.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. So this means that Azure Functions with a consumption plan behind an IoT Hub is a valid approach, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, for IoTHub scenarios, configuring your Function to use a compatible EventHub endpoint is a valid approach.

Comment: Yes, using an AF within the real-time stream pipeline (hot path) is a valid approach, but it is necessary to consider and handle the cold-start time latency of the AF.