# how to retry when call retryQueue.AddSync () also fails?

Tags: c#, azure, queue, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using **Azure Function** **EventHub** **trigger**. The messages coming to EH are very critical and we don't want to miss any. If while processing message from my Event Hub, something happens, I write to my retryQueue as follows:

```
try
{
     await retryQueue.AddAsync (some data from my hub); 
    // if this call also fails, it goes to my catch
}
catch (exception e)
{
    await retryQueue.AddAsync (my eventData); 
    // but what if this call also fails?
}
```

But what happens when AddAsync() call also fails in my catch block? How and where do I save the message for processing later? Is there such thing as IsTransient (which is available in my Service bus queue)?

Comment: In theory, if you fall back to the same Storage account that is used to store progress/offsets, they should either both work or both fail. I don't have enough practical experience though.

Answer (score 0):

**Tolerance for duplicates** - If **check-pointing** fails due to timeout/partition least lost not the error in your function code, then the next EventProcessorHost that gets a lease on that partition will start retrieving messages from the last known checkpoint.

Event Hub guarantees **at-least-once** delivery but not **at-most-once** delivery.

Azure Functions will not attempt to change that behavior. If not having duplicate messages is a priority, then you will need to mitigate it in your workflow. 
As such, when check-pointing fails, there are more duplicate messages to manage if your Function is processing messages at batch level.

For more details, refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901284/azure-functions-event-hub-trigger-bindings).