# Azure Event Hubs - LeaseLostException in CloseAsync of IEventProcessor

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We have the following implementation for `CloseAsync(PartitionContext, CloseReason)` method inside our `IEventProcessor`:

```cs
public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{
    // log reason and partition id

    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
    {
        // log shutdown event
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

We know that LeaseLost exceptions are fine in this method and we saw these threads:

[Azure EventHub & Function LeaseLostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602965/azure-eventhub-function-leaselostexception)

[What is causing Azure Event Hubs ReceiverDisconnectedException/LeaseLostException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496754/what-is-causing-azure-event-hubs-receiverdisconnectedexception-leaselostexceptio)

It used to fail in some calls when the processor was shutting down but it succeeds on others.
Recently, we noticed that it is consistently failing on all calls to `CloseAsync()` when the reason is `CloseReason.Shutdown` and always on the exact same exception `LeaseLostException`. Here is the full exception message and stack trace:

> Message: 'The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob.'

> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager.UpdateLeaseCoreAsync(AzureBlobLease lease)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager.UpdateCheckpointAsync(Lease lease, Checkpoint checkpoint)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionContext.PersistCheckpointAsync(Checkpoint checkpoint)
> at CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionPump.CloseAsync(CloseReason reason)

We are using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs v4.3.0 and Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor v4.3.0

We are concerned that in such a case, no checkpoint is written and on the restart of the processor there will be lots of duplicates due to not being able to save a recent checkpoint location.
Is there a way to understand what is causing the failures and how to fix them?

Comment: You don't mention which version of the library that you're using, but there was a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/14732) in v4.3.0 which would manifest as the behavior that you're describing.  This was [patched](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/15262) in September, but does not appear to have been released.   Unfortunately, I don't have insight into the release roadmap for that library.  You may want to open an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) to inquire when that fix will be released.

Comment: @JesseSquire - Thanks a lot. This indeed seems to be the issue. We are using the 4.3.0 version. However, it seems that it was still not released as you mentioned. I will try to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for trouble. Fix will ship in 4.3.1 release this week.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse Squire mentioned in the comment.
This is due to a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/14732) in v4.3.0 of Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.
It was fixed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/15262), but is not yet released.